# WPF Delete command not accepting command binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm using a DataGrid in a WPF application to display a list of songs, and I've added a context menu with Play and Remove options:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu>
       <MenuItem Command="Play">
       </MenuItem>
       <Separator />
       <MenuItem Command="Delete" Header="_Remove">
      </MenuItem>
   </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

I've added command bindings for both options:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Play" CanExecute="PlayCommand_CanPlay" Executed="PlayCommand_Executed" />
    <CommandBinding Command="Delete" CanExecute="DeleteCommand_CanExecute" Executed="DeleteCommand_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

The Play option in the context menu executes the `PlayCommand_Executed` when selected.  But the Remove option does *not* execute the `DeleteCommand_Executed` method.  It does, however, delete the selected row from the DataGrid.  It's not clear to me why the Play command binding works fine but the Delete doesn't.

All I want to to is display a dialog box to confirm the delete operation before the delete command does its thing.  Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Here is the `DeleteCommand_Executed` method:

```
private void DeleteCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", 
        "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
       e.Handled = true;

}
```

There is nothing syntactically wrong with the program... this method is just not being called.

Comment: please post DeleteCommand_CanExecute

Comment: Are there any binding errors shown in your Visual Studio output window when you do the delete?